# Provided r script matches the requirements or not

Tags: r

I usually work on SQL programming and python but suddenly I have to reverse engineer a piece of code from R, but I would like to know if the logic I found from this code is correct or not. Thanks
update:

The Pr F Site Open, Pr L Subj is a date and time column and Pr # required subj is an integer column

```
Date        Original Projection
11-May-18     0
12-May-19
```

R script:

```
# Builds the "Original Projection" series.
  original.projection <- function() {
    data.frame(
      Date = c(clinAct$`Pr F Site Open`, clinAct$`Pr L Subj`),
      `Original Projection` = c(0L, clinAct$`Pr # required subj`),
      check.names = F
    )
  }
```

#Logic I understood,

A function is defined as Original projection and the column is taken Pr# required subj as input but i am not sure what 0L mean. i also see a function c() is used and i assume its concatenation.

For date column, there is a concatenation between two columns Pr F Site and Pr L Subj

Answer (score 0):

The c() function, will concatenate the values from both columns (`Pr F Site Open` and `Pr L Subj`) together. Now, when you see an L after a number, in R, it means that you want an integer of that number. I recommend, that you run the code below, to see how the c() function concatenate the values of these columns. I separate these two columns, and return it to you, as a list. I made this, because the data.frame structure of R, has a rule, that every column must have the same number of rows. So is likely that your function will trow an error saying "arguments imply differing number of rows", if you mantain these columns together in the same data.frame. Hope I help you in some way.

```
clinAct <- data.frame(
  `Pr F Site Open` = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05")),
  `Pr L Subj` = as.Date(c("2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-01-10")),
  `Pr # required subj` = 1:5,
  check.names = F
)

original.projection <- function() {
  first_column <- data.frame(
    Date = c(clinAct$`Pr F Site Open`, clinAct$`Pr L Subj`),
    check.names = F
  )
  
  second_column <- data.frame(
    `Original Projection` = c(0L, clinAct$`Pr # required subj`),
    check.names = F
  )
  
  return(list(first_column, second_column))
}

original.projection()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, please see the update of the columns. Those are date columns

Comment: The c() function will concatenate, whatever values it is. As long the values of both column's are dates, c() will return a vector with the dates from these two columns. Now, if Pr # required subj is an integer column. Whoever that wrote this function, put an 0L, or in other words, asked for a integer of 0, to assure that R, will not coerce the values Pr # required subj column to decimal number's.

Comment: Could you please update your answer, please with the date type and integers? So I can mark it as answered.

Comment: So the 0L is just to declare its type to be an integer? and not like it populates with 0 values?

Comment: Ecsatly, the 0L, is just to assure that no transformation will occur. When creating vector's in R, you must assure that the types of data are all the same. If you blend values of different types in a vector, R will coerce all values to the most flexible type possible. I put the dates in the format year-month-day, because that is the main format of dates in R.

Comment: why am i getting 20 date values and then the output of original projection is a value from 0 to 10?